# Dynamically changing saturation in css

Tags: jquery, css, hsl

I am creating a stacked bar chart using jQuery a bunch of DIVs. The segments of each stack are colored with different shades of gray. I would like to encode an additional global value onto the bar chart by changing the saturation of the divs to cause their color to vary from gray to some shade color, while preserving the relative brightness. The obvious option is to modify the HSL value of each element individually.

Am I overlooking some more clever way of tweaking the color of the bars? I don't think I can use the background color of the container, as the bars cannot be transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this project](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) would do exactly what you are asking for!

It adds support to animate colors using jQuery.

Check out [this demo](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)

Comment: Animation is not the issue; the question is how to address the elements as a whole while modifying the saturation of all elements.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how you would animate the CSS elements of all of those... perhaps you could post a screenshot and I might have more ideas?

Comment: Before I get into animation, I would like to know if there is a way to change the saturation of a bunch of elements _en masse_ without having to deal with each one individually

Comment: Can't you just address them by class?  like 
$('.satClass').css('color', 'hsl(0, 100%, 50%));

Comment: Well, that would set them all to the same exact *color*. I want them to have different colors, but manipulate the saturation among them. Think about different shades of grey going to different shades of green, while preserving their relative brightness.

Comment: So change the 2nd field in the hsl call?

Comment: So the jQuery color plugin solution sort of works, but is brittle when dealing with 0 saturation. It loses track of the hue & settles on 0 instead. The following work-around, used in combination with semi-transparent divs, solved the problem: `$('.satClass').animate({backgroundColor: $.Color({saturation: Math.max(score, 0.01)})}, 1000);`

Comment: I wrote up a better explanation of what I needed to do to make this work in a separate answer.

Comment: Excellent, this is an interesting problem

Answer (score 0):

I want to document the answer a bit more clearly. Following @Pheonixblade9's advice, I used the jQuery color plugin, but had some trouble getting it to work right.

1. The [latest version](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) of the jQuery color plugin that I got from github didn't work correctly with jQuery 1.4.2; when I upgraded it to 1.4.4, the errors I got related to jQuery.type not being defined went away.
2. I had to change my div structure that I was trying to color to introduce partial transparency to each element. I had up to four overlapping divs that needed coloring, and in the end what worked was setting each div's opacity to 0.3 to produce a legible grayscale range for the four levels I needed. Initially, I had just assigned grayscale values to each div with opacity 1.
3. As I noted in a comment to @Pheonixblade9's answer, the naive solution to varying saturation did not work because if the saturation value ever went to 0, the plugin would lose the hue value, and use 0 instead. To get this to work reliably, I introduced a minimum to the saturation value, which is small enough not to be visible on the monitor (I expect) but sufficient to keep the plugin code from losing the hue.

   ```
   function setSaturation($elem, score, animationDuration) {
        var targetColor = $.Color({saturation: Math.max(score, 0.01)});
        $elem.animate({backgroundColor: targetColor}, animationDuration);
    }
   ```